# jQuery + PHP getting AJAX data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whats the best way to pass data to jQuery AJAX Get method via PHP. And then constructing a query based of that which can be loaded into something via AJAX and displayed on the page.

ex: by clicking viewer.php?note_id=2 a modular window would show and AJAX would get all data in regards to note_id 2 from viewer.php with out going to viewer.php directly.

The problem is that I will be most likely using a list of this notes on the page and are all separated by LI tags.

So what would be the best way to go around this? And assure the correct note_id is passed for the notes from the href link?

PHP code that selects everything for DB will need to fix this since it seems not to follow DESC as well as LIMIT 12 syntaxes

```
    $q_ASL32 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notice ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 12");
   $r_ASL32 = mysql_fetch_array($q_ASL32);

   $nid = $r_ASL32['nid'];
   $note = $r_ASL32['note'];
   $type = $r_ASL32['type'];
   $private = $r_ASL32['private'];
   $date = $r_ASL32['date'];
   $author = $r_ASL32['author'];
```

part 2 of the same PHP code to create notes list from MySQL data

```
 echo '
   <li>
   <p>
   <a href="viewer.php?nid='.$nid.'" id="record-'.$nid.'">
   <img src="16x16/apps/2439.png" />
   &nbsp;
   '.$author.', '.note_type($type).'
   </a>
   </p>
   </li>
   ';
```

jQuery AJAX Part

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "vierw.php",
                   async: false,
                   data: "ajax=1&nid=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
                   success: function(html){
                        $("#note_utm").html(html);
                        $(".loader").html("");
                   }
        });
```

I seem to be getting screwed over by data function in the AJAX call so I think my AJAX call is incorrect

Comment: please post some code from where you are making ajax call ? and make question more understandable if possible.

Comment: Some claryfing would be nice.

Comment: do you have any code? I have a vague idea of you want, and if I'm right I did something like you want... just clarify please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how your might use JQuery to update a notifications area (i.e. a div with an id of "notifications").  This just polls the server every 5 seconds and appends the returned HTML code coming from your server.  Of course, you'll have to make sure your PHP script returns the HTML you described above.

```
  $(function() {  
    setInterval(checkForNotes, 5*1000);
  });

  var checkForNotes = function() {
    $.get('/get_tickets.php', function(data) {
      $("#notifications").append(data);
    },'html');
  }
```

Comment: A that will come in handy, but I updated the my question with more details as asked by others as well as more code provided. Thanks for this truth will be using it to update notes.